# finite variance but infinite higher moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Is it possible to find a positive random variable with finite variance such as
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}(X^{2+\varepsilon})=+\infty
\end{equation*}
for all $\varepsilon > 0$ ?

Equivalently, is it possible to find a random variable $X$ for which
\begin{equation*}
\{p\in\mathbb{R}^{+}, \mathbb{E}(X^{p})=+\infty\}
\end{equation*}
is a non-empty open set?

Equivalently again, is it true or false that
\begin{equation*}L^{1}=\bigcup_{p>1}L^{p} \enspace \text{?}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the series
$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}. $$
Since
$$
\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{x\log^2 x} = \left.-\frac{1}{\log x}\right|_e^\infty = 1,
$$
the series converges.

Define $q_n =  1/(n^3\log^2 n)$ and $Q = \sum_{n=1}^\infty q_n$.
Define a random variable $X$ which is equal to $n \geq 1$ with probability $p_n = Q^{-1}/(n^3\log^2 n)$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2] = Q^{-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^3 \log^2n} = Q^{-1} S < \infty.
$$
On the other hand, for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^{2+\epsilon}] = Q^{-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon} \log^2 n} \geq \Omega(Q^{-1}) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon/2}} = \infty.
$$

Comment: Fixed a small typo.

Answer (score 0):

Any two-parameter [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) where $2 < \alpha \leq 3$ will have that property, as only the moments of the Pareto less than its shape parameter exist.

Comment: Not quite. Only the moments of the Pareto strictly less to its shape parameter exist. So $\alpha=2$, I won't have finite variance; if $\alpha>2$, I will have higher moments...

Comment: Brain freeze, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For posterity, answer has been corrected per @Sergio.

Comment: This still doesn't answer my original question: when I say higher moments I don't necesarily mean integer moments...