# Finite second moment but infinite third moment of difference

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is there a distribution such that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid and have finite variance but their difference $X_1-X_2$ has infinite third moment (i.e., $\operatorname{E}((X_1-X_2)^3)=\infty$)?

Intuitively, it seems that such a thing should exist, as there are distributions with finite variance but infinite third moment (e.g. Pareto with $2<\alpha\leq3$, $t-$ with $2<\nu\leq3$, zeta with $3<s\leq4$). However, I can't think of a solution to this problem, and it seems, based on the amount of recent literature, that convolutions of these distributions are hard to compute.

Comment: You mean $\Bbb{E}((X_1\color{red}{+}X_2)^3)<\infty$?

Comment: Whoops, yeah. Also I meant "$=\infty$", not "$<$".

Comment: Wait no, I meant the difference, my bad.

Comment: Completed the edit work

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085558/finite-variance-but-infinite-higher-moments#1085603. It gives the result even for one variable $X$.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke So it remains to construct $X_1$, $X_2$ iid such that $X_1-X_2$ has discrete density $q_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's better to frame it as $E(|X_1-X_2|^3) = \infty.$ The random variable is necessarily symmettric, so in this case the expectation value $E((X_1-X_2)^3)$ would be undefined, not infinite.

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be Pareto distributed $ f_X(x) = 3x^{-4}$ for $x>1.$ Then $X_1-X_2$ has distribution $$ f_{X_1-X_2}(z)=\int_{1}^\infty f_X(t) f_X(z+t) dt \\= 9\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{t^4(z+t)^4}dt \\= \frac{9}{z^7} \int_{1/z}^\infty \frac{1}{u^4(u+1)^4}du = \frac{3}{z^4}+ O(1/z^5) $$ for $z>0.$ (And it's symmetric.) Thus $E(|X_1-X_2|^3)=\infty.$

Comment: A small potential typo: doing the integral by partial fractions, I got $$\frac{1/3}{z^4}+O(1/z^5),$$ not $$\frac{3}{z^4}+O(1/z^3).$$

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 is that including my $9$ out front?

Comment: oh, it's not. I mean $$\frac{3}{z^4}+O(1/z^5)$$ then.

Comment: Oh, I only saw the first part, didn't see the vastly more important difference $O(1/z^5)$. Yes, that was certainly a typo, thanks.